# Initializing an immutable class with reflection

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection

I have a class that has readonly properties. I am trying to not add setters to it and would prefer that it can be created with the correct values and never changed after.

```
public class Stuff 
{
    public decimal Price { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public Stuff(decimal price, string name)
    {
        Price = price;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

The problem is I may also have a few different classes of this nature. I want to be able to map properties from one text format to actual objects. But I can't use reflection to access the property's set method because there will be none.

That leaves the option of getting the constructor and invoking it. That would be great and all but I don't see a reliable method to retrieve the constructor. The best I see would be passing in a type array to get that specific constructor.

```
var props = typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(p => p.PropertyType).ToArray();
var constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(props);
```

The above may return null depending on the order of the properties. I'm mainly looking for a way to get the constructor, loop through its params by name and order my inputs as necessary.

I know the framework supports serializing and deserializing these kinds of classes so it must be possible. I am just not sure how it's being done.

Comment: Have you looked at [Type.GetConstructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getconstructors?view=netframework-4.8) method?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ 
Edit: Will check that method out. That may be what I need

Comment: Does the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) include ASP.NET? If you don't know in advance what the types are that these things want, how do you know the values?

Comment: The Builder pattern might be useful in this case - the builder could expose it's own setters, then delegate to a private constructor when calling `build()`, where `build()` could verify all required properties were set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches commonly used by serializers here; the first is to recognize it as a tuple pattern, by looking at the constructors. This is awkward and brittle, but perfectly achievable *as long as* there is an exact match by name and type - just look at `Type.GetConstructors()` and look at all orderings.

Perhaps *more common*, however, is to use knowledge of Roslyn.

If we [compile your code](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEDMACFAmDBlGAVwDNiMBYAKAG8qN6tMATOAYwEtIAbDABQXas4GahgDmcGAG4MAXzoN0WAIwAGDADkIYYaInS5C+koIliAChYduGAA4ChAGhXqAdtrgBKIyJ8M+DsIAvHaBUn4MWjoYIe464ZT+8pSyQA), we see:

```cs
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private readonly decimal <Price>k__BackingField;

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private readonly string <Name>k__BackingField;
```

This pattern of `<{property name}>k__BackingField` is pretty reliable and is coded into Rosyln. In reality, it is very unlikely to change, and it works well in *many many cases*. A lot of serializers look for this and use non-public reflection to set the fields. Some also *create* the object **without calling the constructor**, via `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`.

Other common patterns include, for `SomeProperty` - private fields called `someProperty`, `_someProperty`, `m_someProperty`, or the more explicit approach of using an attribute to decorate things.

Comment: I am looking at just getting all constructors using `Type.GetConstructors()` as suggested by @Çöđěxěŕ  earlier and yourself.

The second method wouldn't really work as even though I may find the backing field, it will be read only. I doubt changing it would work even with reflection.

Comment: @Jonathan yes, you can write to readonly fields with reflection - even private ones (but not `static readonly`, in recent runtimes; that is blocked because of JIT reasons). Trust me: this is my area :) For inspiration only (the code is gnarly), here's how protobuf-net looks for this kind of constructor: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/3a2b00dbc736137a58d646ad7b9a02b7bc6d01df/src/protobuf-net/Meta/MetaType.cs#L842-L924

Comment: @Jonathan key point: immutability is a lie - it genuinely doesn't exist, unless you have *very* special hardware; even `string` is mutable; heck, back a few versions (OK, a lot of versions) you could use reflection to change what `string.Empty` contained. Yes, really.